# How do you handle migrating from Server file storage to SPO when it comes to automated 3rd party system file exports?

Tags: migration, file-server

We are migrating from on-prem file servers and FSX servers to SPO. We have some of our business systems that produce reports and currently auto save into the file server. I'd rather not keep the file servers just for these files, so am keen to hear how others have worked a solution for this?

Comment: Do those systems have the ability to export data to locations other than SMB? Or can you instead extract information from those systems via API rather than the system performing an export?

Comment: We can change the save path, but to save files to SharePoint from the system, the system has to have permissions to save to SharePoint. Same would be relevant to an API into SharePoint.